# Determine file path of database

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to run a script that gives the directory and files for all databases installed on a server?

So for example, instead of launching SQL server management studio and checking properties tab for the database and then checking the database files for the data and log file and then doing this for all databases which can be a bit tedious and also assumes we have studio installed.

Thanks
JD.

Comment: @JD: What's your definition of "script"? SQL Server Batch script? Command-line/powershell script? ---- Depending on your answer, both @gbn & @Mitch's answer might be invalidated.

Comment: @gbn: I don't think adding "sql" tag would be appropriate until it is clear what @JD meant by "script".

Comment: Hi Sung,
Not having much experience in SQL-Server apart from writing queries in Studio, I suppose running a SQLCMD with a file that contains the queries mentioned by gdn and Mitch Wheat would be fine.

Can you explain more what you meant by your comments above?

JD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    name AS 'File Name', 
    physical_name AS 'Physical Name', 
    size/128 AS 'Total Size(MB)',
    size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0 AS 
        'Available Space(MB)'
FROM 
    sys.database_files;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id), type_desc, physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

Other info is avaiable from [sys.master_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx), like logical name etc